# Javascript scroll listener not working in chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple slider that on scroll scrolls down 100vh. It works perfectly in Safari but it doesn't seem to fire at all in both Chrome or Firefox.

Really appreciate it if anyone could point out to me where i may have gone wrong. I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't figure it out.

I have uploaded the files to my test web server so you can see the issue.
**test.liamcrane.co.uk**

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.section__wrapper__inner');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var currentTransform = 0;
var activeSection = 0;

function slideDown() {
  if (!(activeSection === sections.length - 1)) {
    sectionReset();
    currentTransform -= 100;
    slider.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + currentTransform + "vh, 0)";
    activeSection++;
    sections[activeSection].classList.add('active');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    ready = true;
  }, 2000);
}

function slideUp() {
  if (!(activeSection === 0)) {
    sectionReset();
    currentTransform += 100;
    slider.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + currentTransform + "vh, 0)";
    activeSection--;
    sections[activeSection].classList.add('active');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    ready = true;
  }, 2000);
}

function sectionReset() {
  sections[activeSection].classList.remove('active');
}

var ready = true;
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (ready && window.pageYOffset > 0) {
    ready = false;
    slideDown();
  } else if (ready && window.pageYOffset <= 0) {
    ready = false;
    slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
.section__wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section__wrapper__inner {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.section span {
  line-height: 100vh;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="section__wrapper">
  <div class="section__wrapper__inner">
    <section class="section"><span>1</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>2</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>3</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>4</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>5</span></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It scrolls for me in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, both work for me. Do you get any errors?

Comment: i think i may have narrowed it down, on my web server when i do a console.log in chrome and firefox looking at window.pageYOffset it keeps returning 0. I think thats why it doesnt seem to be scrolling down for me.

Comment: I have added the files to my test web server so people can see the issue. test.liamcrane.co.uk There are buttons to scroll up and down which work fine as well

Comment: @Reza Sadati Are you sure that scrolling properly for you? (I have chrome73.0.3683.75) and only can scroll down (some time can't scroll to 3-4-5 sections) And scroll up never working for me in chrome. Sometimes it works but the other way around from 1 to 5 never from 5 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is that what you want

I have made a little workarround to force scroll ... maybe a little bit ugly but work see `fakeScroll()` function bellow.

That force the scrollbar to does not reach the beggining and the end. Because in your example above if the scroll bar reach the end ... `scroll` event can't be triggered (same if reach the begining).

I have also changed the conditions and the timming from `setTimeout` (`ready = true`) to 500. You can change it as you want

Sory for my English.

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.section__wrapper__inner');

var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var currentTransform = 0;
var activeSection = 0;

var lastOffset = window.pageYOffset;
var actualOffset = lastOffset;

function fakeScroll(){
  if(lastOffset > 1){
    window.scrollTo(0,lastOffset - 1);
  }else{
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
  }  
}

function slideDown() {
  if (!(activeSection === sections.length - 1)) {
    sectionReset();
    currentTransform -= 100;
    slider.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + currentTransform + "vh, 0)";
    activeSection++;
     sections[activeSection].classList.add('active');
  }
  fakeScroll();
  setTimeout(function() {
    ready = true;
  }, 500);
}

function slideUp() {
  if (!(activeSection === 0)) {
    sectionReset();
    currentTransform += 100;    
    slider.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + currentTransform + "vh, 0)";
    activeSection--;
    sections[activeSection].classList.add('active');
  }
  fakeScroll();
  setTimeout(function() {
    ready = true;    
  }, 500);
}

function sectionReset() {
  sections[activeSection].classList.remove('active');
}

var ready = true;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 
  actualOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (actualOffset > lastOffset) {
    if(ready){
      ready = false;
      slideDown();
    }else{
      fakeScroll();   
    }
  } else if (window.pageYOffset <= lastOffset) {
    if(ready){
      ready = false;
      slideUp();
     }else{
       fakeScroll();    
     }
  }
  lastOffset = window.pageYOffset;
});
```

```css
.section__wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section__wrapper__inner {
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.section span {
  line-height: 100vh;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="section__wrapper">
  <div class="section__wrapper__inner">
    <section class="section"><span>1</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>2</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>3</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>4</span></section>
    <section class="section"><span>5</span></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for you help. it does the job nicely. I just wish chrome and firefox would do everything safari does

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (ready && window.pageYOffset > 0) {
    ready = false;
    slideDown();
  } else if (ready && window.pageYOffset <= 0) {
    ready = false;
    slideUp();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, it still doesn't work in Chrome for me though. I have made the change from document.addEventListener to window.addEventListener on my web server